# EF 6 Code First with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Is DataSeeder supported with the EF 6 code first for the MySQL ? With code first, it created the database for me, but didnt seed it. Is it not supported or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework contains two different methods both called `Seed` that do similar things but behave slightly differently. The first was introduced in EF 4.1 and works with [database initializers](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx). The second was introduced in EF 4.3 as part of [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

If you want to learn more about this subject, check this [blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/).